# My Retrofit Java class keeps returning an error line

Tags: java, android-studio, retrofit2

I am trying to use an API Call to post a data using Retrofit in my Android app. But my UserService Class keeps pointing me to an error in my line of code. I have checked and checked again and can't seem to get the problem.

```
package com.example.xxxxx;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public class UserService {

    @POST("api/enroll_vehicle")
    Call<UserResponse> saveUser(@Body UserRequest userRequest);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrofit works with `interface`s, not `class`es. Change the `class` to `interface`.

In addition, if you had a `class`, the methods there should have a method body. This is likely the error you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have a new challenge.

Comment: My App is meant to post form data using an API. But the API requires a bearer token to come with the data as it returns an `unauthenticated` response on submit. I don't know how to go about it.